# Error in the code shown below - Why is it

Tags: oracle

Why does the following code show an error

```
SELECT TO_DATE('Today is the Seventeenth of December, Twenty Fifteen','"Today is the" Ddspth "of" Month, Year')
from dual
```

Answer (score 3):

Twenty Fifteen is a valid year.

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'Year') as year from dual;

YEAR
------------------------------------------
Twenty Fifteen
```

But what you tried works only one way, you can not parse text like that (with suffixes) into a date type.

[Datetime Format Element Suffixes](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF51083)

> **Notes on date format element suffixes:**
>
> - When you add one of these suffixes to a datetime format element, the return value is always in English.
> - Datetime suffixes are **valid only to format output**. You cannot use them to insert a date into the database.